# Difference between finding asymptotics of Beta function through Laplace versus through Stirling

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, gamma-function, beta-function, laplace-method

Im trying to find the asymptotic expression for the beta function $B(x,y) = \frac{ \Gamma(x) \Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y) } $. Using Stirling's approximation $\Gamma(x) \sim \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{x} } (\frac{x}{e})^{x}$ it's easy to get that for $x,y \gg 1$, $$B(x,y) \sim \sqrt{2\pi} \frac{x^{x - \frac{1}{2}} y^{y - \frac{1}{2}}}{(x+y)^{x + y - \frac{1}{2}}} \equiv G(x,y).$$

However, we can also use Laplace's method: consider $$B(Ma,Mb) = \int_{0}^{1} z^{Ma} (1-z)^{Mb} dz = \int_{0}^{1} e^{Ma \times \ln(z) + Mb \times \ln(1-z)}dz,$$ the function $Ma \times \ln(z) + Mb \times \ln(1-z)$ has a unique maximum at $ z = \frac{a}{a+b}$ so by Laplace's method we can approximate the integral as $M \to \infty$ with:

\begin{align*}\int_{0}^{1} e^{Ma \times \ln(z) + Mb \times \ln(1-z)} dz & \sim \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{M}} (\frac{a}{a+b})^{Ma}(\frac{b}{a+b})^{Mb} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{(a+b)^{2}}{a} + \frac{(a+b)^{2}}{b}}} \\ & = \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{M}} a^{Ma + \frac{1}{2}} b^{Mb + \frac{1}{2}} (a+b)^{-Ma -Mb - \frac{3}{2}}.\end{align*}

Replacing $Ma=x,Mb=y$ we get:

$$B(x,y) \sim \sqrt{2\pi} x^{x + \frac{1}{2}} y^{y + \frac{1}{2}} (x+y)^{-x-y - \frac{3}{2}} = \frac{xy}{(x+y)^{2}} G(x,y) = \frac{1}{2 + \frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x}} G(x,y).$$

So we suddenly get a coefficient that depends on the ratio of $x,y$ as they tend to infinity, whereas earlier we had no such coefficient. I've so far haven't been able to figure out where this difference is coming from since both methods should certainly yield the same result. I would really appreciate it if someone can help me figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: Your integral representation is for $B(x+1,y+1)$ and not for $B(x,y)$.

Comment: @Gary Damn. thanks friend

Comment: Does that fix the problem or no?

Comment: It looks like it does; if you use the functional equation to reduce to something times $\frac{\Gamma(x) \Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$ before using Stirling, then you get $\frac{xy}{(x+y+1)(x+y)} G(x,y)$ for Stirling and $\frac{xy}{(x+y)^2} G(x,y)$ for Laplace. These aren't *identical* but their difference is on the order of the next correction term. I'm not sure whether the same thing happens if you just immediately do Stirling without using the functional equation. Anyway presumably you actually wanted to modify things the other way.